# Concatenation of chars

Tags: c++, arduino, char, string-concatenation, arduino-c++

I need to concatenate to chars and send it as argument to function, but strcat move concatenated chars to first char. I need a method that return concatenated char. Or if I can do it in different way how can I do it?

```
void abca(char *a)
{
  Serial.println(a);
}


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  char *bb = "1";
  char *aa = "2";
  abca(strcat(aa, bb));

}
```

Edit: I'm creating program for Arduino, and I can't use strings. Strings use a lot of memory. Unfortunately Arduino have only 2kB

Comment: "strcat move concatenated chars to first char": What does this mean?  What do you actually want this code to do?

Comment: That's not legal `C++` and also, it has undefined behaviour as you are writing to a constant area of memory.

Comment: Note that _returning_ doesn't mean the same as _printing to the terminal_ (`std::cout << a << std::endl;`)

Comment: Why bother with C functions when C++ functinality is available and you can simply use `std::string`? `std::cout <<(std::string("aa")+"bb") << std::endl;`

Comment: `aa` and `bb` are each pointers to 3 character arrays.  When you `strcat`, you're appending 2 new characters to the 2 characters already in `aa`, going off the end of the array.  This is a bug with undefined behavior.  I'm guessing that when you say, "strcat move concatenated chars to first char" the bug form you are seeing is truncation of `bb` while it appends to `aa`.  You need a separate array with enough space to place the assembled string, i.e., at least a char[5] for the 4 chars + the null.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify what I want. I'm creating a program for Arduino. I have a method that takes char array and prints it to serial. I need to send to this function 2 char arrays, but I need to concatenate them first. I don't want to create new array. Is there any method that create concatenated array and return pointer to this method?

Comment: @ScottHunter, Perette explained what I wanted to write.

Comment: @fabian I can't use strings, because strings use a lot of memory. In Arduino is only 2 kB of memory

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you an error with this line `char *bb = "bb";`. I recommend you check your compiler flags to turn on strict error checking.

Comment: Yes, compiler gives me an strict error. What is better way to write this line?

Comment: Your lines should be of the form: `const char *bb = "1";` because `"1"` is a constant array. If you do that the next error message you get should give you a clue what to do next :)

Comment: I recommend you the CStringBuilder from my StreamLib. It is available in Library Manager. It is simpler than using the C functions. After installing the library, see the example in IDE Examples menu.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code. First of all, you are using `non-const` pointers to `const` arrays:

```
char *bb = "1"; // "1" is a char constant array
char *aa = "2"; // so it needs a pointer to constant memory
```

When you fix that your function calls will fail because they need non-const arrays.

One fix is to create a non-const array to receive your concatenated string:

```
// should be const because it is not modified
void abca(char const* a)
{
    Serial.println(a);
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // char const array decays to pointer to const char
    char const* bb = "1";
    char const* aa = "2";

    // can't concatenate into constant memory
    // abca(strcat(aa, bb));

    // So make some writable memory and concat to that
    char buffer[32]; // long eough for the combined text

    strcpy(buffer, bb);
    strcat(buffer, aa);

    abca(buffer);
}
```

If you don't know how big the resulting string is you may need to allocate `buffer` dynamically to make sure it is big enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the function to

```
void abca(const char *a)
```

Then you could use a `std::string` at the calling site and the `c_str()` method:

```
int main()
{
    std::string a = "aa";
    std::string b = "bb";
    abca((a + b).c_str());
}
```

Note that the overloaded `+` operator is used for concatenation. Better still, if you can change the function to

```
void abca(const std::string& a)
```

(note that the body of the function is unchanged), you can write

```
abca(a + b);
```

at the calling site. All standard C++, and no memory leaks or undefined behaviour either! `std::string` might get some bad press but it does epitomise the power of C++.

Comment: Code abowe is example. I didn't specify what I want to do. I'm creating a program for Arduino. I have a method that takes char array and prints it to serial. I need to send to this function 2 char arrays, but I need to concatenate them first. I don't want to create new array. I can't use strings, because strings use a lot of memory. Arduino have only 2 kB

Comment: @Michal: Have you tried using a `std::string` and found that it is the cause of your running out of memory? `std::string` is pretty lightweight, even if the interface is bloated.